# read xls file - mac program

Tags: cocoa, macos, parsing, xls

I have a little question, I'm a beginner of mac application, I try to do a little program for mac, a program that read some data from a database file (xls) I would ask you where is the best way for parsing an xls file, than I would ask you what is the best format for read (and write) a database file (sqlite,xls,csv,ecc....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.xls` file is in a proprietary binary format, and you need a tremendous amount of work to parse it, and I can't recommend it for a beginning programmer.   If possible, just start from the newer `.xlsx` file, which is a zip file containing an XML file, see e.g. [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).

Saving to a `CSV` file would be an easiest solution for the time being, while you learn your way through programming on a Mac. Later you can learn how to use `sqlite` or, if you're happy with working with Cocoa only technology, how to use the awesome `CoreData` framework.